# Installing quickfix using pip keeps running forever

Tags: python, api, quickfix

Goal: I want to be able to use quickfix

Problem: When running pip install quickfix all I get is the following

[image]

N.B: I waited for the wheel building for around 15 minutes I don't think this should take that much right?

Context: I am using docker and I have the python3.7 image

Tried to fix it:

- downloaded the quickfix-1.15.1.tar.gz file locally and tried to do pip install directly on it
- I checked for the dependencies and what is on the quickfix documentation for linux is glibc I checked and glibc is installed inside my running container

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: the same happened to me with Poetry, took 26 minutes but then I cancel the operation and come here, i will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needs time after waiting for around 20 minutes the build was successful.
I am not sure if this is normal for it to take ~20 minutes but it works. If you don't see an error then keep it running until it's built or it throws an error

Comment: It takes ~20 minutes because it is compiling quickfix behind the scenes, there do not appear to be (m)any prebuild Wheels for quickfix. There are a few Windows versions available here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix